# Need help dealing with emojis (I think?) in PHP strings

Tags: php, emoji

The code below yields this result in https://php-play.dev/

�
and I think the same or similar in my actual web app. How do I extract and use emojis in PHP?

```
<?php
// example code
$bod = "";
$c = $bod[0];
echo $bod."<br>";
echo $c."<br>";
```

I am expecting to see the first emoji character instead of the white-question-mark-in-black-diamond character.

Comment: Emojis are multi-byte characters, and with `$bod[0]` you're only getting the first byte. Try `mb_substr($bod, 0, 1);` instead. See: [mb_substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr)

Comment: I thought [] would do logical characters rather than bytes. That did it -- thank you KIKO Software!

Comment: @TomStewart Be aware that the idea of "logical characters" can get *really* complicated. For instance, Unicode includes separate "code points" for accents, which are *visually* combined with letters, but will still be separated by functions like mb_substr(). In a lot of cases, you might actually want the "grapheme" functions from the Intl PHP module.